# will upgrading my ADSL Modem fix my wireless connectivity

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, wireless-router, modem

Here is my problem:

I have a DSL-2730U ADSL Modem/Router and just bought two D-link DWA-548 Wireless N300 PCI Express Desktop Adapters.
my problem is that one of my Wi-Fi Adapters is far away and when i try to connect it doesn't connect to internet.it connects to modem but it gives me a limited connection(without internet). but when i bring it to the same room as Modem I have Internet connectivity.so distance makes internet unavailable.

here's my question: if I upgrade my modem to a better one like TP-LINK TD-W8968 or D-link DSL-2740U will it fix my problem?

Comment: The second Dlink you mention should have better range than the one you currently have, but without knowing the distances, there is nothing we can actually tell you. I personally recommend buying an Wifi AP instead, and connecting it to your network, closer to your "far away" location.

Comment: i just thought of something my wf-fi adapters carry 2db antennas what if i bought 8db antennas for them? will that fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general that will depend on the distances, obstacles between the access point and your wireless adapters and the antennas on installed on both of them.

Upgrading to better router may not fix your problem if the distance is still too large, or if you have some kind of installation on your building that might disturb the electromagnetic signal, like electricity cables or metal structures.

If the problem is the distance, I would try to install a WIFI range extender  like the TP-LINK TL-WA854RE, or getting better antennas for both the AP and/or the wireless interface depending on your needs and your budget.

If you have a high number of wireless devices connected to the router, upgrading to a multichannel router like the ones you have mention will surely improve the consistency of the signal and the overall connections on the wireless network.

The power of the signal emitted may be another variable to take into account, but in most countries it is strictly regulated.